# Kotlin cannot import packages

Tags: import, kotlin, metadata, package

I'm using kotlin on command line and I'm getting `import` errors `error: unresolved reference: ConnectionHandler`

Following is my directory tree:

```
$ tree .
.                         
├── LICENSE               
├── main.jar              
├── main.kt               
└── server                
    ├── ConnectionHandler.class                      
    ├── ConnectionHandler.kt                         
    ├── HttpRequest.class 
    └── HttpRequest.kt    

1 directory, 7 files
```

When I run `kotlinc main.kt -include-runtime -d main.jar` I get

```
main.kt:2:8: error: unresolved reference: server     
import server.*
```

I have declared `package server` in both of `server/ConnectionHandler.kt` and `server/HttpRequest.kt`

> Note:  The `META-INF` folder is missing. It is not regenerated either on subsequent compilations.

What am I doing wrong? If it has anything to do with `META-INF` folder, how can I regenerate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include all your source files when using kotlinc (or at least include the compiled classes on the classpath). e.g.

```
kotlinc main.kt server/ConnectionHandler.kt server/HttpRequest.kt -include-runtime -d main.jar
```